# Hybris extension and AddOn

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have to install a chinesealipayaddon (already present as deprecated) ,for implements alipay method of payment, in a sub folder of the modules folder in the hybris/bin path. I am following the procedure indicated in the SAP portal but when I am asked to put the following tags in the localestension.xml:

```
<requires-extension name="chinesepaymentservices"/>
<requires-extension name="payment"/>
<requires-extension name="acceleratorservices"/>
```

These tags are red and therefore cannot be put there, same thing if I put them in the extensioninfo.xml. Can any of you tell me the correct procedure?

Comment: requires-extension is for extensioninfo.xml, not localextension.xml, can you give link to the guide that you follow, and please describe what error you get

Comment: @Adiputera Hi, thanks for response I give you the link of SAP help portal guide : https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/cee062b7dd6d4a01882f05cabab13c60.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it like this:

```
    <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />

            <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/modules/core-accelerator/acceleratorservices" />
```

Comment: In localextension.xml or extensioninfo.xml?

Comment: localextensions

Comment: don't work, I can add this tag but in a storefront not appear a alipay method

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through recipes which is having existing integration with alipay.

Recipe Name :b2c_china.

Recipe Gradle which is having a clear injection of alipay-related extensions and add-ons.

Entires of extensions and Add-ons are below.

```
afterSetup {
    ensureAdminPasswordSet()
}    

extensions {

    extensionNames 'adaptivesearchsolr',
     'adaptivesearchbackoffice',
     'adaptivesearchsamplesaddon',
     'adaptivesearchwebservices',
     'commerceservicesbackoffice',
     'solrfacetsearchbackoffice',
     'solrserver',
     'yacceleratorbackoffice',
     'yacceleratorinitialdata',
     'yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess',
     'yacceleratorstorefront',
     'ycommercewebservices',
     'ycommercewebservicestest',

     'electronicsstore',

     'acceleratorwebservicesaddon',
     'orderselfserviceaddon',

     'customersupportbackoffice',
     'customerticketingaddon',
     'commerceorgsamplesaddon',

     'rulebuilderbackoffice',
     'couponbackoffice',
     'droolsruleengineservices',
     'couponfacades',
     'couponservices',
     'promotionenginesamplesaddon',

     'cmswebservices',
     'smarteditwebservices',
     'cmssmarteditwebservices',
     'permissionswebservices',
     'smarteditaddon',
     'cmssmartedit',
     'cmsbackoffice',
     'cmsoccaddon',

     'previewpersonalizationweb',
     'personalizationcmsweb',
     'personalizationsmartedit',
     'personalizationpromotionssmartedit',
     'personalizationsampledataaddon',
     'personalizationpromotionssampledataaddon',
     'personalizationpromotions',
     'personalizationpromotionsweb',
     'personalizationservicesbackoffice',
     'personalizationpromotionsbackoffice',
     'personalizationcmsbackoffice',
     'personalizationsearchbackoffice',
     'personalizationsearchsmartedit',
     'personalizationsearchweb',
     'personalizationsearchsamplesaddon',

     'textfieldconfiguratortemplatebackoffice',
     'textfieldconfiguratortemplateaddon',
     'assistedservicestorefront',
     'assistedservicewebservices',
     'assistedservicepromotionaddon',

     'pcmbackofficesamplesaddon',

     'chineseprofileaddon',
     'chineseprofileoccaddon',
     'chineselogisticaddon',
     'chineselogisticbackoffice',
     'chineselogisticoccaddon',

     'chinesepaymentaddon',
     'chinesepaymentoccaddon',
     'chinesepaymentmock',
     'chinesetaxinvoiceaddon',
     'chinesetaxinvoiceoccaddon',
     'chinesetaxinvoicebackoffice',
     'chinesepspalipaysamplesaddon',
     'chinesepspalipaysbackoffice',
     'chinesestoreaddon',
     'verticalnavigationaddon',

     'chineseaddressaddon',
     'chineseaddressoccaddon',
     'chineseaddressbackoffice',

     'chinesepspwechatpaymentaddon',
     'chinesepspwechatpaysamplesaddon',
     'chinesepspwechatpaysbackoffice',

     'consignmenttrackingaddon',
     'consignmenttrackingmock',
     'consignmenttrackingbackoffice',

     'notificationaddon',
     'customerinterestsaddon',
     'stocknotificationaddon',
     'chineseproductsharingaddon',

     'selectivecartaddon',

     'customercouponaddon',
     'customercouponsamplesaddon',
     'customercouponbackoffice',

     'timedaccesspromotionengineaddon',
     'timedaccesspromotionenginesamplesaddon',
     'timedaccesspromotionenginebackoffice',
     'timedaccesspromotionengineoccaddon',
     'messagecentercsoccaddon',
     'consignmenttrackingoccaddon',
     'customerinterestsoccaddon',
     'customercouponoccaddon',
     'notificationoccaddon',

     'outboundservices',
     'odata2webservices',
     'odata2webservicesfeaturetests',

     'kymaintegrationbackoffice'
}

addons {

    forStoreFronts('yacceleratorstorefront'){
        names 'chineseprofileaddon,chineselogisticaddon,chinesepaymentaddon,chinesetaxinvoiceaddon,chinesepspalipaysamplesaddon,chinesestoreaddon,verticalnavigationaddon,chineseaddressaddon,chinesepspwechatpaymentaddon,chinesepspwechatpaysamplesaddon,consignmenttrackingaddon,notificationaddon,customerinterestsaddon,stocknotificationaddon,chineseproductsharingaddon,selectivecartaddon,customercouponaddon,customercouponsamplesaddon,commerceorgsamplesaddon,promotionenginesamplesaddon,smarteditaddon,textfieldconfiguratortemplateaddon,assistedservicestorefront,assistedservicepromotionaddon,customerticketingaddon,orderselfserviceaddon,adaptivesearchsamplesaddon,timedaccesspromotionengineaddon,timedaccesspromotionenginesamplesaddon,personalizationsearchsamplesaddon,pcmbackofficesamplesaddon'
        template 'yacceleratorstorefront'
    }

    forStoreFronts('ycommercewebservices'){
        names 'acceleratorwebservicesaddon,messagecentercsoccaddon,consignmenttrackingoccaddon,customerinterestsoccaddon,customercouponoccaddon,notificationoccaddon,cmsoccaddon,chineseaddressoccaddon,chinesetaxinvoiceoccaddon,timedaccesspromotionengineoccaddon,chineselogisticoccaddon,chineseprofileoccaddon,chinesepaymentoccaddon'
        template 'ycommercewebservices'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where I find this?

Comment: After extraction of the hybris zip, there will folder installer::--->then path installer/recipes

Comment: I found the file and this is the result ( // china-accelerator-alipay-psp
            extName 'chinesepspalipaysamplesaddon' // deprecated
            extName 'chinesepspalipaysbackoffice'
            extName 'chinesepspalipayservices' )   Then exsist one: (addons { forStorefront (yacceleratorstorefront) {  not present 'alipay'})

Comment: which hybris version are u using?

Comment: Hybris version 2205.0

Comment: any solution for the problem?

Comment: still I see you can include the extension ,even if it's deprecated based on given reference.

Comment: yes and I followed the steps in the guide but the alipay method does not appear.